# How do you re-learn a subject that you've started to forget?

Tags: learning

Due to my lack of revision I've realized that I have started to forget most of the organic chemistry that I had learnt a few months back (spend about 3 m/o on a textbook). I'm trying to think of how to get back my edge but I can't seem to figure out the best way to get back the working knowledge I had.

A brute force approach I thought was to reread the whole textbook, but it is a horrible idea to do as it sounds. So, other than direct prevention methods (revision) , how does one relearn what he once knew in the most efficient way possible?

Note: Currently my understanding is vague recollections of all the chapters I've done. Btw I've solved most of the textbook exercises already :p (though I'd probably  not be able to answer a particular question offhand right now)

Comment: Why do you need to remember it, MCAT?

Answer (score 3):

If you took notes when you first learned the material, then start with those, and perhaps summarize them. Then, or if you don't have notes, I'd suggest going back to the exercises and doing them again, starting with the first chapter, rather than a random approach. Perhaps a few from each chapter. If you get stuck, then review the material enough to get to a solution.

If you really did *know* it, then it should come back with a bit of practice. Hopefully you weren't just kidding yourself on the first "learning". Then it is much harder.